# Suspending already executing task NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I have problem suspending the current task being executed, I have tried to set `NSOperationQueue` `setSuspended=YES` for pausing and `setSuspended=NO` for resuming the process.

According to [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html)  I can not suspend already executing task.

> If you want to issue a temporary halt to the execution of operations, you can suspend the corresponding operation queue using the setSuspended: method. Suspending a queue does not cause already executing operations to pause in the middle of their tasks. It simply prevents new operations from being scheduled for execution. You might suspend a queue in response to a user request to pause any ongoing work, because the expectation is that the user might eventually want to resume that work.

My app needs to suspend the time taking upload operation in case of internet unavailability and finally resume the same operation once internet is available. Is there any work around for this? or I just need to start the currently executing task from zero?

Comment: if destination of your upload supports upload resuming (e.g. web-server) you can save offset of last uploaded byte when connection fails and restart from that position when connection is available again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to start from zero. otherwise two problems will come there. If you resume the current uploading you cant assure that you are not missed any packets or not. At the same time if the connection available after a long period of time, server may delete the data that you uploaded previously because of the incomplete operation.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you can resume or pause a operation queue is not your issue here...
If it worked like you imagined it could (and it doesn't) when you get back to servicing the TCP connection it may very well be in a bad state, it could have timed out, closed remotely...
you will want to find out what your server supports and use the parts of a REST (or similar) service to resume a stalled upload on a brand new fresh connection.

If you haven't yet, print out [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) and put it on the walls of your cube, make t-shirts for your family members to wear... maybe add it as a screensaver?